# How can we choose $z$ to make this series absolute convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, absolute-convergence

I have the following series:

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^{\ln (n)}}{3^n} (z+2)^n$

The question is, how can we choose $z \in \mathbb{C}$ to make this absolute convergent?

For the first sight it seemed impossible to have such $z$, since $n^{ln n}$ should be way way bigger than $3^n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Am I wrong? Any hints, ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Well there's at least one good value of $z$, and that is $z=2$...

Comment: Why is $z=2$ good?

Comment: Sorry, i meant $z=-2$...

Comment: Yeah $z=-2$ seems to work, I am wrong with the $n \rightarrow \infty$ thing, thanks. Any ideas in general? :)

Comment: If $z>1$, I am sure it can't work.

Comment: The term $n^{\ln n}$ is tiny compared to the denominator. So $|z+2|\lt 3$ will give us convergence.

Comment: Try the root test eh.

Comment: I assume $n^{lnn}$ is really $n^{ln(n)}$

Comment: @mlu . I fixed it to clarify it.......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reciprocal of the radius of convergence, as given by the [Cauchy-Hadamard Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem) is
$$
\begin{align}
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^{\log(n)}}{3^n}\right)^{1/n}
&=\frac13\limsup_{n\to\infty}n^{\log(n)/n}\\
&=\frac13\limsup_{n\to\infty}e^{\log(n)^2/n}\\
&=\frac13e^{\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\log(n)^2/n}\\[3pt]
&=\frac13
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, for $\left|z+2\right|\lt3$, the series is absolutely convergent.

For $\left|z+2\right|=3$, the absolute value of the terms of the series is $n^{\log(n)}$, which does not tend to $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Take the $n$th root of the $n$th term to get $n^{(\ln n)/n}(|z+2|/3).$ Show $n^{(\ln n)/n} \to 1.$ Thus the root test gives convergence if $|z+2|/3 < 1,$ divergence if $|z+2|/3 > 1.$ You can also check that the series diverges when $|z+2|/3 = 1.$

Answer (score 1):

To estimate $n^{\ln n}$, you can use

$$n^{\ln n} = e^{\ln(n^{\ln n})} = e^{\ln n \ln n} = e^{\ln^2 n}$$

and

$$3^n = e^{\ln(3^n)} = e^{n \ln 3}$$

Which should tell you which of these grows quicker (does $n$ grow quicker than $\ln^2 n$?)